# Does using this "shortcutting function" is a good practice?

Tags: c++, events, messaging

I have a **event based communication system**, and this is the simplifed version of it:

**class A:** contains elements derived from class B

**class B:** has a pointer to its owner A

So when a B wants to communicate with other B-s, it calls **A's Broadcast()** method:

- m_owner->Broadcast();

But I was wondering:

- Should I make a protected **Broadcast() method for B**, which is just this:

  - m_owner->Broadcast();

**Pros:**

- Instead of m_owner->Broadcast() I can write just Broadcast()

  - this makes the code cleaner.

**Cons:**

- There will be +1 function calling in the procedure.

  - But this can be avoided by making the method **inline**

**Is this a good practice? Why yes and why not?**

Comment: I think this is going to get closed as "primarily opinion based".  Personally, I would add the method.  It's that much less clutter when reading.  (Although I'd consider making it protected, not private.)

Comment: @MartinBonner oh yes, that's a typo, thanks. If it will be closed, that means that the answer is purely opinion based. Which means that I can use whichever I want, and it doesn't have side effects. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Tudvari If you are worried about the extra function call then I would suggest you compile and check the assembly.  The optimizers nowadays are really quite good and it might just optimize the extra call away.

Comment: A separate function will at least be very helpful if in future you need to add other code to it. A mutex lock, for example, or logging.

Comment: Why do you believe it is a con to call another function? It is arguably more important to write code that is easier for humans to read and understand than it is to write something that you think is optimized (without benchmarking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation that you have described, it probably indeed does not make much difference.

But in future you may find that you will need to add extra code to each place where `Broadcast` is called, for example logging or mutex locking. In this case, a separate function will be really useful.

Also you mention that you have classes *derived* from `B`. If this is a *derived* class that calls `m_owner->Broadcast()`, and `m_owner` is a base class field, then this is not a good pattern. Derived classes should better access parent's protected functions, not directly data members.

Comment: +1 for "_Derived classes should better access parent's protected functions, not directly data members_." However, @Tudvari, you should also ask yourself if it makes sense to say "a B broadcasts". If, for example, it makes more sense to say "a B asks its owner to broadcast" then B's method should probable be called something like `RequestBroadcast`. Without you telling us what classes A and B actually are, we can't help much.